# Axis scale with bins

Tags: matplotlib, axis, bin

Anyone know how to generate this plot in matplotlib (any ideas is OK)?
Basically, I have some data points, I want to plot them using bins.
After, for example, 100 points, I draw a x tick. This x tick is probably scaled.
Thanks,[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ticks wherever you want them to be using [`set_xticks`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html).

Comment: Yes, I know that. But the data in the above plot is not linear.

Comment: You have to somehow have a place to set you ticks.  If your axes aren't standard (linear or log), you just set them on a standard axis and label them something else.